# rails angularjs html5mode webrick or nginx rewrite rule configure how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, url-rewriting, angularjs, webrick

i have angularjs app with html5mode enabled.

I have tried to run app in IE8 and it seems that URL is being prefixed with #! is it suppose to be - back button works etc..hashbang mode

I have tried to run app in modern browser and it seems that history api also work. All fine.

But if i hit `http://localhost:3000/notes` directly in address bar in both browsers i get routing error from webrick/rails app. I thought angular will take over of this request and handle it.

**I have NOT setup anything on server side as angular guide say:**

> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you
>   have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application
>   (e.g. index.html)

Is that why i am getting route error from webrick? And if i will able to setup rewriting rule how the hell it works? I thought if i rewrite something like `http://localhost:3000/notes -> http://localhost:3000`(index if u wish) the "/notes" - where i want to jump in is gone and angular app will never know where to route..

And if there is no way to tell webrick what and how to rewrite. How do you do in your development environment?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your server to return the same data for `/notes` as if it were the `/` route. Not a redirect (since that will remove `notes`). Basically you need a catchall route that returns if it doesn't match anything else. Either that or enumerate the known routes (i.e., `/`, `/notes`, `/other`, etc.), and have all of those return the same document. At that point, angular will detect the path and act accordingly.

Comment: understood, thank you for your answer. I assume i need to rewrite all routes except static assets (images, scripts..) any idea how to tell webrick anyone? I would like to stick with it..

Comment: okey, i have used nginx with passenger instead. Adding this rewrite rule `rewrite ^/(?!assets)/* / last;` seems to work perfectly. I am not sure if is 100% correct regular expression, but better than nothing.